# Is there a diff tool launcher for Git that lets you interactively select from a file listing?

Tags: git, git-diff

When I use Git difftool it launches my diff program on each file in sequential fashion, where I have to close the tool and hit the Enter key between each one.  Is there a way to have it launch a listing of the changed files where I can then interactively choose which file to launch the diff tool on?  I'm used to Windiff which works in this way.

Comment: 'gitk --all' turned out to be closest to what I was looking for.  Ironically I've been using gitk for a while but didn't realize I could simply right-click and choose 'External diff' to launch a diff tool from the file listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gitk --all` is what most people here use to fly around looking at changes introduced by commits and it will also show any changes that you have currently.

EDIT:

Just wanted to add that during an interactive rebase `gitk --all HEAD &` is a great help. As you go through the rebase, refresh gitk's view to see what's going on. While rebasing, adding 'HEAD' is needed as otherwise you won't see the results of your last `git rebase --continue`.

Answer (score 1):

May not be exact answer, but `git gui` should serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

[TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) displays a list of changed files. You can double-click one to open it in a diff viewer.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that because it doesn't make a distinction between staged and unstaged since it has no concept of index.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd specify the filename on the command line directly:

```
git difftool path/to/file
```

If typing out the name of the file on the command line is too cumbersome for you then have a look at (warning shameless plug ahead!) [git-number](https://github.com/holygeek/git-number).